# LaserScan ranges values - left and rightmost scans

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, range, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a for loop to print out values retrieved from a Kinect LaserScan (specifically the "ranges" array).  It returns 360 values, each with a number - most of the numbers are 11, but occasionally the numbers from 142-257 (I can't remember the exact range but it's something like that) are different.  I believe these are the laser ranges? Am I wrong?  Also, what are the numbers measure in? I normally get numbers between 0.5 and 10.  If i'm mistaken, could someone explain how to get laser ranges from a kinect laser scan (i'm trying to get the leftmost and rightmost scans)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31455/laserscan-ranges-values---left-and-rightmost-scans./) by [AmaneSuzuha](https://answers.ros.org/users/1879/amanesuzuha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sensor_msgs/LaserScan message is documented at http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html which is linked from the [sensor_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2